# Select2 load Multiple Options From MySql JSON Array

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have Multiple Value Select2 Which have options generated from MySQL using inline PHP when we submit the form the select2 is encoded into json_encode ["43", "23", "32"] What I want is when user want to edit I make a follow as the user clicks on the button and ajax call is sent to MySQL and in response, we get all values and what I need is show json_encoded array into Select2, it works fine with single value but not working with multiple
If the value is single value its work but in my case its json_array

```
$(".select2Custom").select2({theme: 'bootstrap4'}).val(data.product_id).trigger('change');
```

[The Result which I Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS1CR.png)
[The Result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EWls.png)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @Arman Your Solution is Not Giving Me 100% Solution But Give Me the Vision to Solve My Problem like your hint to convert the array into Select2 acceptable Array :) Here is Solution

I Got JSON_ENCODED Array From Ajax Response `["33", "44", "23"]` What I Need is to Show those Options which have id in an array

and here is Solution

//I Just Convert Ajax Response into proper JSON and its Works

```
var data_array = $.parseJSON(data.product_id);                    
$(".select2Custom").select2({theme:"classic"}).val(data_array).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make same format json as the select2 accepts like:

```
{"id": "1","text": "some text"}
```

So convert your initial json with this method:

```
processResults: function (data) {
        return {
            results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
                return { id: obj.mysql_json_id, text: obj.any_text_you_want_display };
            })
        };
    }
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v1kd82zs/) 
Edit: Changed fiddle so we select2 can render this array `["32", "44", "40"]`

Comment: Thanks Arman But i Have value Similar ["32", "44", "40"] from ajax response but i need to render on Select2 the option of select2 is Loaded using Inline PHP like <option value="">~~SELECT~~</option>
                  <?php $q = get($dbc,"products WHERE product_sts = 1");
                    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)):?>
                      <option value="<?=$r['product_id']?>"><?=$r['product_description']?></option>
                  <?php endwhile ?>

Comment: Well that is bad design to use php to make select2 options, instead you should make ajax request for select2 options and render them with js. And if your select2 options not dynamic than pass them instantly on page load with all page data

Comment: I think i can use it next time but will you please clarify how can i convert this ["32", "44", "40"] array into array accepted for Select2?

Comment: Please check updated answer and fiddle, still same map method but without key just object itself is written for options

Comment: or you mean in php?

Comment: Thanks Man But still I think I do not make it clear. I don't need array as option i need the array as the selected option from all option loaded in select2 :(

Comment: you want `32,43,53` selected and displayed like this separated by comma?

Comment: I want to Accept your Answer But my Reputation is Below 15 anyway Thanks Man! made my Day

Comment: can anyone please upvote my question i got banned and i need some other help please